# Como concatenar uma variável no meio de outra variável?

Tags: php

Gostaria de fazer com que o conteúdo de uma variável formasse outra variável, por exemplo:

```
$name = 'clientes';
$default_$name_list = "Lista de clientes";
```

Quero fazer com que a variável default seja `$default_clientes_list`, há alguma maneira de fazer isso em PHP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode chegar a algo parecido usando [variáveis variáveis no PHP](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.variables.variable.php).

```
$name = 'clientes';
$lista_var = "default_{$name}_list";
$$lista_var = "Lista de clientes";

echo $default_clientes_list;
```

Veja [funcionando](https://3v4l.org/0uYue).

Ou até [simplificando mais um pouco](https://3v4l.org/pJ7uu) sem atribuir para a variável intermediária.

```
$name = 'clientes';
${"default_{$name}_list"} = "Lista de clientes";

echo $default_clientes_list;
```

Na minha opinião, não recomendo seguir essa linha. Isso prejudica bastante a legibilidade do código sem ter um benefício aparente. Só deixa mais complexo e difícil para quem vai ler o código.

Comment: Boa resposta. Só para reforçar que essa prática é ma, adiciono outro ponto ao que você já disse. É possível de também substituir valores de outras variáveis locais que existam com o nome gerado, sem que a pessoa se aperceba, criando bugs difíceis de detetar. [Pequeno exemplo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7d81ecd83187b65beca45f0fe2c325b8e2f4570d)

Answer (score 3):

Olha não sei se isso você pode fazer, mas você pode fazer em array.

Por exemplo:

```
$name="clientes";
$defaultList['clientes']= "Lista de clientes";
$defaultList['representantes'] = "Lista de representantes";
```

e aí você puxa o que quer:

```
echo $defaultList[$name]; // Lista de clientes;
```

Answer (score 1):

No seu exemplo não funciona pois o PHP está procurando pela variável `$name_list`, que não existe.

Para obter o efeito que você quer, acho que seria desta forma.

```
$varName = sprintf("default_%s_list", $name /* ou 'clientes' */);
$$varName = /* você terá uma variável $default_clientes_list com o valor que passar aqui */;
```

Entretanto também não recomendo esta prática. Neste caso e em vários outros parecidos acredito que seja melhor o uso de [Arrays](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.array.php).